# SQL update to remove postcode from address (where postcode is already in a separate column)

Tags: sql

I have an issue where the postcode was included in an address field for hundreds of records. The postcode is already provided in a separate column.

How to I perform a SQL update to remove just the postcode from the end of the address field in all records that contain the contents of the post_code field at the end address field?

Example:

```
address                            | post_code
1 Street View, Somewhere, 1AA AA1  | 1AA AA1
2 Road Place, Some City, 2AA AA2   | 2AA AA2
```

After SQL update:

```
address                            | post_code
1 Street View, Somewhere           | 1AA AA1
2 Road Place, Some City            | 2AA AA2
```

Thanks

Comment: I think that currently nobody answered, because you did not show any attempt/effort/code how you already tried to resolve this problem. Can you add some SQL update commands that you tried already, but failed so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following update query:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable
SET address = REPLACE(address, ', ' + post_code, '')
WHERE address LIKE '%, ' + post_code;
```

If the trailing post code be *not* comma separated, then use this version:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable
SET address = REPLACE(address, ' ' + post_code, '')
WHERE address LIKE '% ' + post_code;
```

Comment: Thanks I've just noticed, some of the address lines are not separated by commas in the address column. How should the above code be amended to account for both commas and no commas ?

Also can you include the Concat() version as my version of SQL doesn't like ||

Comment: You still haven't told us what your version of SQL is.  I strongly suggest you do that.

Comment: Very good point. SQL Server 2012 SP4 (11.0.7001)

Comment: Also happy for two separate scripts for addresses with commas an addresses without.